# Notation for "$(a_1, .\dots, a_n)$ where each element is either $0$ or $1$"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

> Suppose I have a vector $(a_1, .\dots, a_n)$ where each element is either $0$ or $1$.

Is it correct to write this in the following notation:
$$
(a_1, .\dots, a_n), \quad a_i\in\{0,1\} \quad ? \tag 1
$$
Can I also write it as:
$$
(a_1, .\dots, a_n) \in \{0,1\}^n \quad \tag 2?
$$
Or something else?

***Update based on the comments:***

Maybe I explicit should include $\mathbb N$? 
So something like:

For $\mathbb N = \{1,2, \dots, n\}$ we have
$$
(a_1, .\dots, a_n), \quad \forall a_i\in\{0,1\} \tag 3
$$
Or
$$
(a_1, .\dots, a_n) \in \{0,1\}^n \tag 4
$$

Comment: Both your notations are correct. In (1), I would also explicitely write $\forall i$.

Comment: The second on is more elegant.

Comment: Is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed?

Comment: Agree with @MichaelHoppe but I think both options are possible.

Comment: Hi! @Taroccoesbrocco What do you mean with "fixed"? In this case I guess $\mathbb N = \{1,2,\dots, n\}$

Comment: @JDoeDoe - Are all the vectors of the same length?

Comment: Why are you putting an extra `.` before `\dots`?

Comment: (3) doesn't really make sense, $\forall a_i\in \{0,1\}$ would mean you're quantifying a single variable $a_i$ over the set $\{0,1\}$. Something like $\forall i\in \{1,\dots,n\} \ a_i\in\{0,1\}$ would work.

Comment: Typically, $\mathbb{N}$ denotes the set of natural numbers, which is not finite.  As you have written it, $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,\dotsc,n\}$ contains only a finite number of elements (specifically, it contains $n$ elements, whatever $n$ is).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the notation $2^n$, and see every "vector" as the image of a function $$f:n\longrightarrow 2$$ $$i\longmapsto a_i $$ Where every $a_i\in 2$, and $2$ is the Von Neumann ordinal of cardinality $2$ ($2=\{0,1\}$)